# String filtering commas and numbers

Tags: python, parsing

I want to filter a string in Python, to get only commas `,` and numbers `[0-9]`.

```
import re
x="$HGHG54646JHGJH,54546654"
m=re.sub("[^0-9]","",x)
print(m)
```

The result is:

```
5464654546654
```

instead of:

```
54646,54546654
```

Comment: are you sure you got `54546654`? I tried your code and got `5464654546654`

Comment: yes u right, it is 5464654546654

Comment: look at your regex, make sure it specifies that it's looking for `,`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your current code, you simply match `[0-9]`. Simply add a comma `,` as a valid character, and use a backslash to escape to the literal (`\,`):

```
import re
x="$HGHG54646JHGJH,54546654"
m=re.sub("[^0-9\,]","",x)
print(m)
```

**Outputs:**

```
54646,54546654
```

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) have further information regarding other special characters that must be escaped with a backslash to acquire the literal, such as `?` and `*`.